# Issue with configuring caching with Spring's ResourceHandlerRegistry

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, browser-cache, cache-control

I am trying to configure cache control for a single page application using Spring's `ResourceHandlerRegistry`.

I need for the `index.html` page **not to be cached** and for all other classpath resources (already revved CSS and JS) **to be cached**.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
@Configuration
@Profile(Profiles.CLOUD)
class CloudWebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final int ONE_YEAR = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")//
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/")//
                .setCachePeriod(ONE_YEAR);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/")//
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/index.html")//
                .setCachePeriod(0);
    }
}
```

However, looking at the response headers in the chrome console indicates that the `index.html` page is cached too:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:5000
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date:Wed, 26 Aug 2015 20:09:14 GMT
Expires:0
Last-Modified:Wed, 26 Aug 2015 19:58:27 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context:application:cloud:5000
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

See the `304 not modified`...

For your information, here is how I serve the `index.html` (it maps to `/`):

```
    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    }
```